# Rails - Test::Unit - testing that number is greater than 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3

My post model has a sequence attribute that I want to make sure is numerically greater than 0:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :sequence, :presence => true,
                       :uniqueness => true,
                       :numericality => { :greater_than => 0 }
```

Great. Now I'm trying to make the following test pass.

```
  test "post is not valid if sequence is negative" do
    post = Post.new( :title => "Unique Title",
                     :description => "Some text",
                     :sequence => -1)
    assert !post.save
    assert_equal I18n.translate('activerecord.errors.messages.greater_than'),
                  post.errors[:sequence].join('; ')
  end
```

But it fails with this output:

```
1) Failure:
test_post_is_not_valid_if_sequence_is_negative(PostTest) [/test/unit/post_test.rb:46]:
<"translation missing: en.activerecord.errors.messages.numericality.greater_than"> expected but was
<"must be greater than 0">.
```

Obviously rails doesn't like the following line `'activerecord.errors.messages.greater_than'`

So what argument do I need to pass the **I18n.translate** method in order to test that the sequence is greater than 0?

PS:
I read the section titled **5.1.2 Error Message Interpolation** on [this page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) and thought my code would work, but obviously I've got it wrong.

Comment: I have temporarily fixed this by using `assert_equal "must be greater than 0", post.errors[:sequence].join('; ')` - which will do for now, but I would prefer to use the I18n.translate method if I can

Comment: Translate simply picks up the string defined in locales/*.yml files. But the "path" to the string `en.activerecord.errors.messages.numericality.greater_than` does not exist in en.yml - you need to define it.

Comment: the path to `activerecord.errors.messages.taken` is not defined in en.yml either but I can still use it in my other tests. I don't think this is to do with locales/en.yml to be honest, rather I suspect that I'm missing an argument